# Calculate binomial sum

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I have problem with the following sum for $n \ge k \ge 0$: $$\sum_{i=0}^k (-1)^i i \binom{n}{i} \binom{n}{k-i}$$

I've tried to use $i\binom{n}{i} = n\binom{n-1}{i-1}$ which give me the form $$n\sum_{i=1}^k (-1)^i \binom{n-1}{n-i} \binom{n}{k-i}$$

and here I stuck.

Comment: Did you try for some small values ? It seems that there is a pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We start with OPs second     form omitting the factor $n$. It is convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[z^k]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^k$ in a series. This way we can write e.g.
\begin{align*}
  [z^k](1+z)^n=\binom{n}{k}\tag{1}
  \end{align*}

> We obtain for $1\leq k\leq n:$
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{i=1}^k}&\color{blue}{(-1)^{i}\binom{n-1}{n-i}\binom{n}{k-i}}\\
> &=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}(-1)^{i+1}\binom{n-1}{i}\binom{n}{k-1-i}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{i=0}^\infty(-1)^{i+1}[z^{k-1-i}](1+z)^n[u^i](1+u)^{n-1}\tag{3}\\
> &=-[z^{k-1}](1+z)^n\sum_{i=0}^\infty(-z)^i[u^i](1+u)^{n-1}\tag{4}\\
> &=-[z^{k-1}](1+z)^n(1-z)^{n-1}\tag{5}\\
> &=-([z^{k-1}]+[z^{k-2}])(1-z^2)^{n-1}\tag{6}\\
> &=\left\{\begin{array}{rc}
> \color{blue}{(-1)^{\frac{k}{2}}\binom{n-1}{k/2-1}}&\qquad\color{blue}{ k\equiv  0(2)}\\
> \color{blue}{(-1)^{\frac{k+1}{2}}\binom{n-1}{(k-1)/2}}&\qquad \color{blue}{k\equiv 1(2)}
> \end{array}\right.\tag{7}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (2) we shift the index $i$  to start  with  $i=0$  and use the binomial identity  $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{p}{p-q}$.
- In (3) we apply the *coefficient of* operator twice. We also extend the upper range of the series to $\infty$ without changing anything since we are adding zeros only.
- In (4) we do some rearrangements and use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and apply the rule $[z^{p-q}]A(z)=[z^p]z^qA(z)$.
- In (5) we use the substitution rule of the *coefficient of* operator with $u=-z$
  \begin{align*}
    A(z)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_iz^i=\sum_{i=0}^\infty z^k[u^i]A(u)
    \end{align*}
- In (6) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator again to swallow a factor $(1+z)$.
- In (7) we select the coefficient of $[z^{k-2}]$ resp. $[z^{k-1}]$ according to even and odd $k$.

Comment: Verified. (+1).

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Many thanks, Marko. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Observe that
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^k (-1)^i i \binom{n}{i} \binom{n}{k-i}&=[x^k]\left[
-nx(1-x)^{n-1}\times(1+x)^n
\right]\\
&=[x^{k-1}]\left[\frac{-n}{1-x}(1-x^2)^{n}\right]\\
&=-\sum_{m=0,\, \text{even}}^{k-1}n\binom{n}{m/2}(-1)^{m/2}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[#ffd,10px]{\ds{\sum_{i = 0}^{k}\pars{-1}^{i}\, i{n \choose i}{n \choose k-i}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\sum_{i = 0}^{\color{red}{\large\infty}}\pars{-1}^{i}\, i{n \choose i}\bracks{z^{k - i}}\pars{1 + z}^{n}\qquad\qquad
\pars{\begin{array}{l}
\mbox{Note that}\ \ds{{n \choose k - i}_{\ i\ >\ k} = 0}
\end{array}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bracks{z^{k}}\pars{1 + z}^{n}
\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}\pars{-z}^{i}\, i{n \choose i} =
\bracks{z^{k}}\pars{1 + z}^{n}\
\bracks{z\,\partiald{}{z}\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}{n \choose i}\pars{-z}^{i}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bracks{z^{k - 1}}\pars{1 + z}^{n}\,\partiald{\pars{1 - z}^{n}}{z} =
-n\bracks{z^{k - 1}}\pars{1 + z}^{n}\pars{1 - z}^{n - 1}
\\[5mm] = &
-n\bracks{z^{k - 1}}\pars{1 + z}\pars{1 - z^{2}}^{n - 1} =
-n\bracks{z^{k - 1}}\pars{1 - z^{2}}^{n - 1} -
n\bracks{z^{k - 2}}\pars{1 - z^{2}}^{n - 1}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
\ds{-n{n - 1 \choose \bracks{k - 1}/2}\pars{-1}^{\pars{k - 1}/2}} &
\mbox{if} & \ds{k}\ \mbox{is}\ odd
\\[3mm]
\ds{-n{n - 1 \choose k/2 - 1}\pars{-1}^{k/2 - 1}} &
\mbox{if} & \ds{k}\ \mbox{is}\ even
\end{array}\right.} \\ &
\end{align}